# How to create a Wind Rose in KML format (google earth) using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, kml, simplekml, windrose

I need to create a Wind Rose KML file to be opened in google earth with as (similar to) the following pictures.

[image: Wind rose in google earth 1]
[image: Wind rose in google earth 1]
[image]

I can create wind roses using `windrose` python module, like this one:
[image: wind rose in python]

And I know how to create KML points and lines in python using `simplekml` module like this one:
[image]

Does anyone know any package capable of doing that?
or any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use matplotlib when draw windrose, try to save the fig with following opthons.

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('windrose.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, transparent=True)
```

After you got the image file, generate ground overlay code in kml.

```
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml(open=1)

doc = kml.newdocument(name='sample', open=1, visibility=0)

ground = doc.newgroundoverlay(name='windrose example')
ground.icon.href = 'windrose.png'
ground.altitudemode = simplekml.AltitudeMode.absolute
ground.altitude = 500.0
ground.latlonbox.north = 38.031368255615234
ground.latlonbox.south = 37.11344909667969
ground.latlonbox.east =  141.5791015625
ground.latlonbox.west =  140.4208984375
ground.visibility = 1

kml.save('sample.kml')
```

Each values are need to adjust.

Please refer following, if you'd like to know more about ground overlay.

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/altitudemode#absolute

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Earth.
2. Draw a static picture\chart like wanted one over a map.
3. Save it into a KML file.
4. Open with any text editor.

It must show you an example which lead you to generate a valid KML with your data.